# Cache JWKS in Lambda memory vs in temp

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, auth0

I currently am retrieving a JWKS keys using [the Auth0 JWKS library](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/) for my Lambda custom authoriser function.

As explained in [this issue on the JWKS library](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/pull/141), apparently the caching built into JWKS for the public key ID does not work on lambda functions and as such they recommend writing the key to the tmp file.

What reasons could there be as to why `cache=true` would not work?

As far as I was aware, there should be no difference that would prevent in-memory caching working with lambda functions but allow file-based caching on the `tmp` folder to be the appropriate solution.

As far as I can tell, the only issues that would occur would be from the spawning of containers rate-limiting JWKS API and not the act of caching using the memory of the created containers.

In which case, what would be the optimal pattern of storing this token externally in Lambda?

Comment: What a terrible github issue... Why is there no explanation or reference as to why the original caching does not work. I would answer your first question with "yes", the second one with "good question" and the third one with "no idea (yet)".

Comment: @luk2302 Exactly my thoughts. I was ridiculously confused by it. Is there any implementation specific reason as why an LRU (which if I'm not mistaken is some form of queue system) cache wouldn't stay active in memory on AWS lambda? I think the real issue is that if at scale, opening new lambda containers still rate limits the endpoint then it'd be better to cache the key in something like redis. But this is independent of whether or not the default caching works or not - more an optimisation to ensure no rate limits

Comment: I think I will follow up on the Github in reference to that issue, asking exactly why it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of option how to solve this. All have different advantages and disadvantages.

First of, storing the keys in memory or on the disk (`/tmp`) has the same result in terms of persistence. Both are available across calls *to the same Lambda instance*.

**I would recommend storing the keys in memory, because memory access is a lot faster than reading from a file (on every request).**

Here are other options to solve this:

1. Store the keys in S3 and download *during init*.
2. Store the keys on an EFS volume, mount that volume in your Lambda instance, load the keys from the volume *during init*.
3. Download the keys from the API *during init*.
4. Package the keys with the Lambdas deployment package and load them from disk *during init*.
5. Store the keys in AWS SSM parameter store and load them *during init*.

As you might have noticed, the "during init" phase is the most important part for all of those solutions. You don't want to do that for every request.

**Option 1 and 2** would require some other "application" that you build do regularly download the keys and store them on S3 or a EFS volume. That is extra effort, but might in certain circumstances be a good idea for more complex setups.

**Option 3** is basically what you are already doing at the moment and is probably the best tradeoff between simplicity and sound engineering for simple use cases. As stated before, you should store the key in memory.

**Option 4** is a working "hack" that is the easiest way to get your key to your Lambda. I'd never recommend doing this, because sudden changes to the key would require a re-deployment of the Lambda, while in the meantime requests can't be authenticated, resulting in a down time.

**Option 5** can be a valid alternative to option 3, but requires the same key management by another application like option 1 and 2. So it is not necessarily a good fit for a simple authorizer.

Comment: Regardless thank you for your answer @Jens I'm going to go with option 1 and use S3. When the key is invalidate due to a different ID being served to the authoriser, I will request the new key and replace the S3 file with that key + load it to memory on each init

Comment: @Jordan think about allowing your Lambda to update the keys stored in S3. This is poor separation of concern. From a security perspective, it just feels wrong for the authorizer to have write-access to those keys. Furthermore, one could craft a malicious JWT that contains the wrong `kid`. You then would go and download _your_ new JWKS that would not contain that `kid`. That would not be a security problem perse, but if you receive such a request 1 million times, it can become a problem. So I would only rotate those keys on S3, when you know they changed. Maybe a webhook by your IDP?

Comment: That makes sense. The key is only a public key for verification not signing but I can understand that allowing a malicious user to spam incorrect keys would be an issue. Auth0 unfortunately doesn't provide any webhook for when the keys change. I could perhaps set up a scheduled lambda that pings it periodically and checks for changes before updating the S3. Would that be a solid approach?

Comment: @Jordan You could check this: [Stream Logs to AWS Eventbridge](https://auth0.com/docs/logs/streams/stream-logs-to-amazon-eventbridge). Apparently, you can send events about administrative changes to event bridge. I would think/hope that includes admins rotating keys. That means, you can create a Eventbridge rule to look for those changes that then trigger the key update Lambda. I did not test this (yet), but this could be what you are looking for.

Comment: could be perfect. I'll take a look, thank you! Didn't even know that was there. First time implementing Auth0 today so it's been fun! Thanks again. Else I'll implement some sort of active watcher on a cronjob or schedule of some sort

Comment: You can use EventBridge to run Lambdas on a schedule doing stuff like this.